# Can't Attach Disk to Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sdk, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to attach a pd-balanced 5TB disk to an instance, but got this error.

Instance type: e2-medium (2 vCPUs, 4 GB memory) | with ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200916  image

Editing VM instance abcdef failed. Error: Maximum persistent disks size should be less than [3072] GB (combined disk size including boot disk), Requested : [5010] GB

thanks

Comment: You need to use a more powerful instance type, which has higher limits for the attached disks.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized there's a restriction in shared core machine

Shared-core machine types are limited to 16 persistent disks and 3 TB of total persistent disk space.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#disk-types